# How to obtain the lowest multiple of a number entered as input, that isn't the entered number itself?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to obtain the lowest multiple of a number that is not itself,and I cannot figure out a way to do it. Let's assume I have a Search Binary Tree of numbers.

I want to find the lowest multiple of the root of the tree, that is not the root itself. So, if I have the following values on a given tree: [2, 6, 4, 9, 12], I want to find the lowest multiple of 2, which in this case would be 4. 
Now, when I code this, all the algorithms I come up with return the lowest multiple of the root, which is... itself. How can I find the "4" I am looking for?

PS: Apologies if the question is weirdly phrased, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Please include the code of the algorithm you're talking about.

Comment: Nobody can answer this without more information. The test for whether a multiple of a number is not the number itself is simple, but we cannot tell why your code does not handle that correctly without seeing your code. Analyze your code and figure out whether it is traversing the tree properly, whether it is correctly determining whether a value is a multiple of the number, and whether it is correctly determining whether a candidate multiple is not the number itself. If you still have trouble, reduce the code to a reproducible example and post that.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is quite simple. Given x = value at the root of the tree, you write a recursive function which returns the smallest multiple of x which is greater than x which is found in a tree, or 0 if there is no such multiple of all.

```
int recursive (node* root, int x) {
    int result = 0;
    if (root->value > x && root->value % x == 0)
        result = root->value;
    if (root->left != NULL) {
        int left = recursive (root->left, x);
        if (left != 0 && (result == 0 || left < result))
            result = left;
    }
    if (root->right != NULL) {
        int right = recursive (root->right, x);
        if (right != 0 && (result == 0 || right < result))
            result = right;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you call int result = recursive (root, root->value).